# Auto Highlighting identical lines text

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

I saw a skilled vim ninja do this a while back but I have no idea were to start.

A) Is there a way to set up vims background colour so that consecutive lines with identical content get highlighted.

B) If somebody knows how to do that a nice tweak to this would be if the highlighting happened on consecutive lines but only consider the first word (not the whole line).

A second tweak if the highlighting could be configured to different colours are used based on the number of matching lines (or words depending on A B is active). So of we only have two consecutive lines that match then green,  3-5 consecutive lines then orange, 6+ then red.

Comment: Similar post: [Folding by regex search pattern](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2165/778)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following `match` sets seem to work for (A):

```
:syn match Low /\v(.+)\n(\1\n)/
:syn match Medium /\v(.+)\n(\1\n){2,4}/
:syn match Critical /\v(.+)\n(\1\n){5,}/
:hi Critical  ctermfg=red
:hi Medium  ctermfg=yellow
:hi Low  ctermfg=green
```

It seems the order is crucial here. If the `Low` or `Medium` matches come after `Critical`, it gets subsumed by the looser requirements of these, and similarly for `Low` w.r.t. `Medium`.

The highlighting doesn't appear immediately after you add, say, a 3rd or 6th dupe line, but once you move around a bit after adding them. I'm not sure what triggers it, exactly.

For B, I imagine you could replace the regex with:

```
/\v(\S+).*\n(\1.*\n)/
```

In general, replace all the `(.*)` with `(\S+).*` and `\1` with `\1.*`, or whatever constitutes a word for you.

Comment: I gave this answer the tick because to me its how to do the highlighting that I needed (as expressed by the question). @Matts regular expression nice but does not answer the actual question I asked (changing the highlighting).

Answer (score 8):

As a starting point, here's a search pattern that matches duplicate lines (ignoring changes in leading whitespace):

```
              \zs                marks start of the pattern. Everything before here will not be highlighted
 ^                               start of the line
  \s*                            leading whitespace
       .\+                       match 1 or more non-newline characters
     \(   \)                     and use parens to capture this in match group 1

            \n                   match the newline character
                 \(        \)\+  1 or more
                      \1         copies of what was in the match group 1
                   \s*  \n       with leading whitespace followed by a newline
/^\s*\(.\+\)\n\zs\(\s*\1\n\)\+   the full regex
```

`:help pattern` will provide more info on how to make regexes like this

`:help syntax` will show you how to take this regular expression and turn it into something that is highlighted for you

Learning to write syntax scripts can be tough, so a good short-term solution is to do this 'on the fly' by making sure `'incsearch'` is set so that searches are highlighted and mapping a key to do the above search, i.e. `nnoremap <F5> /^\s*\(.\+\)\n\zs\(\s*\1\n\)\+<CR>`

Comment: Is there some automated way of distributing the regex like that? It provides such a clear depiction.

Comment: I've been doing it by hand. The easiest quick way in vim would be to do something like `yy10p` on the line with the full regex then select parts you wish to remove and hit `r<space>`. Maybe I'll add a command for 'replace everything except the selection on this line with spaces' to speed things up a bit.

Comment: Wow! That is quite some effort!

Comment: I made a (really ugly) vim function to make this a bit faster: https://gist.github.com/mattboehm/da63a48eedf6f14375aa . Select a line, hit `,r` then join lines together with `<space>` in normal/visual mode.